# Can not find getPageSource method in visual studio 2017

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, visualstudio, chromedriver, selenium-webdriver-c#

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and found that class ChromeDriver does not contains method `getPageSource()`.      Does anybody knows why?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
```

> Error CS1061  "ChromeDriver" no contiene una definición para
>   "getPageSource" ni se encuentra ningún método de extensión
>   "getPageSource" accesible que acepte un primer argumento del tipo
>   "ChromeDriver" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de
>   ensamblado?)  SeleniumTest    C:\tfs\CHI-VT-DEV\04-Programación\VisualTIME\Test\Functional\SeleniumTest\InMotionGIT.Test.Selenium.cs  29  Activo

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code where you are calling getPageSource

Comment: Additionally, could you update the error message to English?

Answer (score 1):

The *getPageSource* method, in C#, is actually a property:

```
string html = this.driver.PageSource;
```

See [PageSource documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver_PageSource.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In C# (VS) you should to use:

```
string html = this.driver.PageSource;
```

instead of

```
driver.getPageSource();
```